# Trying to make a world mesh that I can change at will c++ OpenGL

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, glut, gltools

So, I have a project I am trying to build.  My goal is to have a list of GL_QUADS that hold my level structure.  Basically I want to be able to add and remove cubes from a list and then have OpenGL render it.

My problem is that arrays dont seem to be expandable.  I have allready written a code that allows me to press space and create a cube, however I need someway to create make the array of points that creates the cube longer at will.  So basically if there is a way to expand arrays as needed I am all ears.

Here is some of the code... you might not need to even look at it to answer the question.  I have sudo coded out irrelivant sections.

```
#include <GLTools.h>    
#include <GLMatrixStack.h>
#include <GLFrame.h>
#include <GLFrustum.h>
#include <GLBatch.h>
#include <GLGeometryTransform.h>

#include <math.h>
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <glut/glut.h>
#else
#define FREEGLUT_STATIC
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif


// An assortment of needed classes
GLShaderManager     shaderManager;
GLMatrixStack       modelViewMatrix;
GLMatrixStack       projectionMatrix;
GLFrame             cameraFrame;
GLFrame             objectFrame;
GLFrustum           viewFrustum;


GLBatch             triangleBatch;
GLBatch             QuadStrip;

GLGeometryTransform transformPipeline;
M3DMatrix44f        shadowMatrix;


GLfloat vGreen[] = { 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };


 GLfloat vPyramid[12][3] = { //COORDS};




//This function is triggered when space is pressed.  It takes parameters passed to it to create the 8 points of the cube then makes a Quad_Strip mesh from it
void CreatePlat(float centerx, float centery, float centerz, float width, float length, float depth)
{

    GLfloat vP1[3] = { (centerx - (width/2)), (centery), (centerz + (length/2))}; //top left
    GLfloat vP2[3] = { (centerx + (width/2)), (centery), (centerz + (length/2))}; //top right
    GLfloat vP3[3] = { (centerx + (width/2)), (centery),(centerz - (length/2))}; //bottom right
    GLfloat vP4[3] = { (centerx - (width/2)), (centery), (centerz - (length/2))}; //bottom left
    GLfloat vP5[3] = { (centerx - (width/2)), (centery - depth), (centerz + (length/2))};
    GLfloat vP6[3] = { (centerx + (width/2)), (centery - depth), (centerz + (length/2))};
    GLfloat vP7[3] = { (centerx + (width/2)), (centery - depth),(centerz - (length/2))};
    GLfloat vP8[3] = { (centerx - (width/2)), (centery - depth), (centerz - (length/2))};



    GLfloat vPlat[26][3] = {vP4[0], vP4[1], vP4[2],
        //BLA BLA
        vP2[0], vP2[1], vP2[2]};


    QuadStrip.Begin(GL_QUAD_STRIP, 26);
    QuadStrip.CopyVertexData3f(vPlat);
    QuadStrip.End();


}

GLfloat size = 1.0;


void Update ()
{

    //Controls

    //Rotate controls

    if(space)
        CreatePlat(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, size, 1.0, 1.0);
    if(W)
        size += 1.0;
    if(S)
        size -= 1.0;

    vPyramid[1][1] += 1.0;
}


void SetupRC()
    {
    triangleBatch.Begin(GL_TRIANGLES, 12);
    triangleBatch.CopyVertexData3f(vPyramid);
    triangleBatch.End();

    }


void DrawWireFramedBatch(GLBatch* pBatch)
    {
           //Take a mesh and draw it WITH outlines
    }

void RenderScene(void)
    {    
        Update();
        // Clear the window with current clearing color
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

        modelViewMatrix.PushMatrix();
        M3DMatrix44f mCamera;
        cameraFrame.GetCameraMatrix(mCamera);
        modelViewMatrix.MultMatrix(mCamera);

        M3DMatrix44f mObjectFrame;
        objectFrame.GetMatrix(mObjectFrame);
        modelViewMatrix.MultMatrix(mObjectFrame);

        shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_FLAT, transformPipeline.GetModelViewProjectionMatrix(), vBlack);


        DrawWireFramedBatch(&triangleBatch);
        DrawWireFramedBatch(&QuadStrip);

        modelViewMatrix.PopMatrix();
        glutPostRedisplay();

        // Flush drawing commands
        glutSwapBuffers();
    }


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
    gltSetWorkingDirectory(argv[0]);

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_STENCIL);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("GL_POINTS");
    glutReshapeFunc(ChangeSize);
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);
    //glutSpecialFunc(SpecialKeys);

    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "GLEW Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
        return 1;
        }


    SetupRC();

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
    }
```

As you can see a desirable solution would be inside of the CreatePlat() function after creating the lines, to add lines to an array, then rebuild my buffer to suit with it.  Also you may notice currently I am using Quad_Strip.... I will be using GL_Quads.

***Side note I am planning to do a sorta velocity based movement, I am familiar with the math of how to deal with orientation in 2D if your trying to add varying ammounts of horizontal and vertical velocity.... However in 3D IDK! I will be able to set things up to work perfectly, up until the player rotates which is when things get complicated.  It sheir a math3d lib thing for this?***

Comment: use std::vector<GLfloat> if having a constant array adress is not an issue

Comment: Can you explain what that does?  Std is my name space right?  Then I am telling it the name "vector"  and giving it data type "gl float"?  Is this right?   If it is then how to I add a vertical to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use a VBO instead of QuadStrip  and render it with a basic shader program. This can speed up your program a bit and gives you way more freedom.

Comment: Could you point me to a tutorial on how to use those or tell me how?  I am very new to this...  I am currently using an old version of opengl superbible I found at a garage sale.   This project I'm working on is really small and will never hit the game market.  I doubt I will be needing to worry about efficiency too much, however I am completely open to learning.  I am trying to learn opengl as best as I can.

Comment: Yes.. for example http://in2gpu.com/opengl-3/ . Even for small project it's better to use the new approaches. You can also google Modern OpenGL tutorials.